# Programmatically Can't Align ImageView in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm having trouble adding an imageview to a relative layout.  I would like to add an image to a list of menu items that I am creating dynamically using RelativeLayout.  All of my menu items show up just fine and in order but when I try to add an image to each of the items I only get one arrow and it is not centered vertically.  Below is my code.

In my XML file

```
<RelativeLayout 
            android:id="@+id/pMenu"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        </RelativeLayout>
```

In my code:

```
private void buildMenu(String name, int id) {

    String[] menuItems = getResources().getStringArray(pMenus[id]);
    // Get the rel layout from xml
    RelativeLayout container = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.pMenu);

    int imageId=1;
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(),"mreavesmodot-reg.otf");
    for(String menuItem: menuItems) {           

        // Defining the layout parameters
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);


        StyledButton menuImage = new StyledButton(this);
        menuImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.menu_button);
        menuImage.setText(menuItem);
        menuImage.setTypeface(tf);
        menuImage.setTextSize(19);
        menuImage.setPadding(20, 0, 0, 0);
        menuImage.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        menuImage.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        menuImage.setOnClickListener(getOnClickListener(menuImage, name));
        menuImage.setId(imageId);

        if(imageId==1) {
            lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
        } else {
            lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW ,imageId-1);
        }
        menuImage.setLayoutParams(lp);


        ImageView arrow = new ImageView(this);
        arrow.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow_menu);
        arrow.setPadding(0, 0, 15, 0);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams( RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT );
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_RIGHT,menuImage.getId());
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);

        arrow.setLayoutParams(params);

        container.addView(menuImage);
        container.addView(arrow);

        imageId++;
    }
}
```

Comment: could you add a screenshot showing what is happening? I know you explain, but an image might be more descriptive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the line below is your problem

```
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
```

YES, you are most likely adding multiple arrows, they are just simply one on top of each other ALL aligned to the vertical center of the full relative layout.  That command is not performing a vertical centering against your button item, but agains the parent RelativeLayout.

Comment: that was in fact the problem with my code.  I ended up using RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF.  that worked for me.