# Android - In RelativeLayout, ImageView is not showing in the specific area

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-relativelayout

I'm new to android.
I'm trying to make a simple application.
There are two buttons(left and right) and an image.
Image moves left or right according to the clicked button.

The problem is like the following pictures :
[LEFT button is clicked multiple times](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6O5K.png)
[RIGHT button is clicked several times](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O83Ri.png)

Moving left is OK, but when the image moves right, the image will disappear behind something. Please, let me know why the image disappears and how to fix this problem.

This is activity_main.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.alticast.avoidpoo.MainActivity">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relative_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/buttonLinearLayout"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttonLinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_left"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/left"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_right"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/right"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is MainActivity.class.

```
package com.alticast.avoidpoo;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int layout_width;          // the width of relative layout
    int layout_height;         // the height of relative layout

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        init();
    }

    public void init() {
        Button btn_left = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_left);
        Button btn_right = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_right);
        btn_left.setOnClickListener(moveBtnClickListener);
        btn_right.setOnClickListener(moveBtnClickListener);

        final RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative_layout);
        ViewTreeObserver vto = relativeLayout.getViewTreeObserver();
        vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new     ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                layout_height = relativeLayout.getMeasuredHeight();
                layout_width = relativeLayout.getMeasuredWidth();
            }
        });
    }

    View.OnClickListener moveBtnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            ImageView img_android = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_android);
            int id = view.getId();
            if (id == R.id.btn_left) {
                int x = img_android.getLeft();
                if (x-10 <= 0) return;
                img_android.setLeft(x-10);
            } else if (id == R.id.btn_right) {
                int x = img_android.getLeft();
                if (x+10 > layout_width-img_android.getWidth()) return;
                img_android.setLeft(x+10);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

==============================================================================
I solved this problem by using setLayoutParams() methods.
Guessing that calling setLeft () directly on the image view seems to be a bad idea. It seems to be the key to using LayoutParams.

The new MainActivity.class is the following. :

```
View.OnClickListener moveBtnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        ImageView img_android = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_android);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)img_android.getLayoutParams();

        int id = view.getId();
        if (id == R.id.btn_left) {
            if (params.leftMargin-10 < 0) return;
            params.leftMargin = params.leftMargin - 10;
        } else if (id == R.id.btn_right) {
            if (params.leftMargin+10 > layout_width-img_android.getWidth()) return;
            params.leftMargin = params.leftMargin + 10;
        }
        img_android.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
};
```

In activity_main.xml, I just removed 'android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"' from the image view.

```
        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/buttonLinearLayout"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
```

Comment: If I am correct then you want to move Image from left to right on button click ? SO it would be animation style for simple visible for button click ?

Comment: @Target Yes, you are right, but I didn't use animation. I used setLeft() methods on ImageView.

Comment: post related class file

Comment: can you please post your whole xml

Comment: I added main_activity.xml and MainActivity.class.

Comment: why don't you use set margin from right/left instead of this?

Comment: take two images..and set the condition for hide and show

Comment: programmatically use layout_alignParentRight or left to imageview

Comment: Y are you using set left and right

Comment: see this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10973730/programatically-cant-align-imageview-in-relativelayout

Comment: Thank you, I solved this problem. I changed margin with setLayoutParams(). I added the new code above.